# How to share the http response between two components in angular 6?

Tags: html, angular

I have a component named modal. In this model ts file, Im making a http request to get json data from node js. After retrieving Im just displaying it in a table format. My table structre is like below.

```
modalId   modalName  subModal  AddSubmodal
111        modal1                add      
112        modal2                add
```

The problem here is after clicking the add button, one pop up box will come(Another component) asking us to enter sub model name. There we should display the modal name for which we have to enter sub model details.

So After clicking the add button, I need to pass the modalId to fetch the model details. So here I need to pass the modalID dynamically to the addmodel(second) component. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

My modal.component.ts:

```
 @Component({
selector: 'app-modal',
templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
 export class ModalComponent extends Lifecycle {
 public d: any;
 constructor(
    private $modal: $ModalManagerService,
    private http: HttpClient,
) {
    super();
}
 _initialize(): void {          
   this.http.get('/getModel',{responseType:"json"}).subscribe(
   response => {
       this.data = response;
        var sample=JSON.stringify(response);
      });
    }
addSubmodal(modalId){
 let obj = this.$modal.show(AddSubModalComponent)
        .subscribe(r => {
            obj.unsubscribe();
        });

};
```

My modal html:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>modal ID</th>
        <th>modal Name</th>
        <th>SubModal</th>
        <th>AddSubmodal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let i of d">
        <td>{{ i.Record.modalId }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.Record.modalName }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <img src="./../Add_Icon.svg" (click)="addSubmodal(i.Record.modalId);">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

As I'm new to angular, Im just browsing angular answers in stackoverflow & doing it. Please tell me how to achieve this in my second component html file?

Comment: Do you have any errros in the console?

Comment: use service to share data across multiple component

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara No

Comment: @Chellappan Can you pls give me an example?

Comment: @Priyanka You can use Observables in your service to share data among components.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/api-demo check this example

Comment: @jai  Can you pls give me an example ?

Comment: @Priyanka in your case it is too broad but a search can help you with this. Look for `Subject` or `SubjectBehavior` of rxjs.

Comment: What is in `addSubcategory()`?

Comment: @Jai Sorry that is addsubmodal. I have updated.

Comment: @Chellappan Thank you. But I need to pass a parameter while calling the function.

Comment: you can pass the parameter from component to service then fetch data

Comment: you can use ngrx store, after your http call dispatch an action to set the redux store and then you can get the result everywhere you need just by doing store.select('you data')

Answer (score 1):

**Use Input & Output Decorators**

Basic concept ---> [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-harudq)

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-component1 (elm)="catch1Data($event)">

</app-component1>
<app-component2 [elm]="datatocomp2" *ngIf="datatocomp2"></app-component2>

parent component : {{datatocomp2 | json}}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
 datatocomp2: any;

  catch1Data(data) {
    console.log(data)
    this.datatocomp2 = data;
  }
```

**component1.ts:**

```
@Output () elm : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();



objectData: any;

  constructor() { }



 ngOnInit() {
    let objectData = {
      comp: 'component 1',
      data: 'anything'
    }

this.objectData = objectData;
this.elm.emit(objectData)
  }
```

**component2.ts:**

```
@Input() elm: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.elm);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared service to share data between components, event emitter method isn't the best way for components in routing

Simple example , create a datashare service

**//DataShare Service**

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class DatashareService {

    private dataObs$ = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);

    getData() {
        return this.dataObs$.asObservable();
    }

    updateData(data) {
        this.dataObs$.next(data);
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

**In the component where you fetch data,**

```
import { DatashareService } from '../datashare.service';
```

**update the value of the observable**

```
this.dataService.updateData(this.modal_id);
```

**Subscribe to the observable from the sub components**

```
import { Component, OnInit,OnDestroy,NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { DatashareService } from '../datashare.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

**In the constructor,**

```
 constructor(private dataService: DatashareService
  ,private zone:NgZone){}
```

**Now, access data on init,**

```
 ngOnInit() {


        this.subscription.add(this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => { 
           this.zone.run(()=>{
               console.log(data);
               this.modal_selected=data;

            })

        }))

             }
```

**Don't forget to unsubscribe on destroy**

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();

    }
```